# Expression to capture only 1 occurrence for a single character but multiple for others

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use the following regex to capture following values. This is for use in Java.

```
(\$|£|&#36;|&#163;)([ 0-9.]+)
```

Example values which I do want to be captured via above regex which works.

```
$100
$100.5
&#36;100
&#36;100.6
&#163;200
&#163;200.6
```

But the following as gets captured which is wrong. I only want to capture values when there
is only 1 dot in the text. Not multiples.

```
&#163;200.15.
&#163;200.6.6.6.6
```

Is there a way to select such that multiple periods doesn't count?

I can't do something like following cos that would affect the numbers too. Please advice.

```
(\$|£|&#36;|&#163;)([ 0-9.]{1})
```

Comment: Sorry, do you need to match anything in the last two examples? Or avoid matching anything in them? Are these standalone strings or part of longer strings? My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68115675/3832970) will work for both substring and full string matches, but the first question needs to be cleared out.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need to match. Ultimately I only care about the number value from above Strings. In order, I want to capture 100, 100.5, 100, 100, 200, 200.6 from above.

Comment: But are these standalone strings? Like `String text = "$100";` or `String text = "... $100 ... text...";`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Was validating it against my Strings. Was trying to amend it to not have the first matcher since I only need to match the 2nd one. But this does work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
(\$|£|&#36;|&#163;)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b(?!\.)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK004m/1).

In this regex, `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b(?!\.)` matches

- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1: one or more digits, then an optional occurrence of `.` and one or more digits
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\.)` - not immediately followed with a `.` char.

Another solution for Java (where the regex engine supports possessive quantifiers) will be

```java
(\$|£|&#36;|&#163;)(\d++(?:\.\d+)?+)(?!\.)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK004m/3). `\d++` and `(?:\.\d+)?+` contain `++` and `?+` possessive quantifiers that prevent backtracking into the quantified subpatterns.

In Java, do not forget to double the backslashes in the string literals:

```java
String regex = "(\\$|£|&#36;|&#163;)(\\d++(?:\\.\\d+)?+)(?!\\.)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
(\$|£|&#36;|&#163;)([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$
```

one or more digits followed by an optional dot and some digits and then the end of the string.

EDIT: some typos fixed

And it's not ok to delete the whole sentence obove, due to one word against my self. :(